# DockPanel Doesn't Show Children

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's my MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" Height="200" Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="ViewData">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Name="splMain" Background="{StaticResource GreyGradient}"></DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And here's the code for dynamic children creation:

```
 private void ViewImgData(SubPod subPod)
        {
            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate(subPod.Image.Src);
            DockPanel.SetDock(wb, Dock.Top);
            ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).splMain.Children.Add(wb);

        }
```

This method gets called at least twice and yet in the output window only 1 image is visible. Where did I get wrong?

EDIT: This is how I am calling The `ViewImgData` method:

```
foreach (SubPod subPod in pod.SubPods)
                        {
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                             DispatcherPriority.Background,
                             new Action(() => ViewImgData(subPod)));
                        }
```

EDIT: Is it possible to achieve my intentions with any other control? Thanks?

Comment: Did you check what children splMain does have when the method is called before and after you add the new webbrowser? Additionally remove SetDock and LastChildFill to be sure they´re not somehow responsible. Is there enough space for the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both WebBrowser controls have the Dock property set to Top and the WebBrowser has no minimum width. Meaning the first control will collapse in favour of the 2nd. Try setting the Height/MinHeight property for each WebBrowser or choose some different parent control (why do you use a DockPanel?).

Comment: Can you suggest a better option then DockPanel? Maybe add some code to show how I can put it to work? It would really help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe DockPanel is the right panel for your needs. If you want all the controls to have an equal height, maybe a Grid would be better. But you would need to add a row definition for each control and set the height to * (star).

Comment: If you just want to show Images, consider using a ListView or ListBox with actual <Image> elements.